# MongoDB Community Edition

Tags: database, mongodb

I have recently started to work with databases in general and used MongoDB as my first database. Still, I have a question regarding MongoDB for which I couldn't find an answer on the website of MongoDB. My aim is to use MongoDB local which is why I am using the community edition, but I don't know if it allows me to save as much documents as my hardware allows or is there any limitation of savings such as in MongoDB Atlas (which is 512 MB)?
I hope that someone from the stack overflow community who is familiar with MongoDB could help me with my question.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Atlas is a paid-for service, and storage size is one of the differentiators between payment tiers. No such concern in self-hosted installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no database size limits in the community edition.